# Error: SP.ClientContext().get_current throws uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I´m following this conference workshop http://video.ch9.ms/sessions/spc/2014/SPC261.mp4 where they teach you, how to create a sharepoint App

At some point I have this script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //get context and then username
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_Current();
    web = context.get_web();

    //get the tasks for the user
    getTaskCountForUser();


});
```

It will simply count how many tasks are remaining in a Task list.

I have in the app part aspx file the next script included

```
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/QuickTask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Everything seems to work just fine. App part is shown in SharePoint Online, I can include it in the home but the script just won't work and throws `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` right in the line

```
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_Current();
```

I tried enclosing that segment like this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
   //my code above in here

}, "sp.js");
```

But in that case the same error is thrown in the first line.

What am i missing? I´m using a Sharepoint E3 online account from my MSDN subscription, Vsual Studio 2013 and in the video, the guy just go seamless through it.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have some typos in your code, links to debug js files (not that this is incorrect, but why do you need them?) and error in getting ClientContext object.

To fix script include problems use following script tags instead of yours:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js" ></script>
```

But the main problem is in this line:

```
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_Current();
```

You do not need to use `new` keyword in this case, you are getting context object using getter.
It should be:

```
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

Also notice case of `get_current()` function - `current` word should start from lower case character.

Comment: I just change the case of the get_current method and it worked. So sad  to spend such a ong time in such a n00b mistake. The rest of your suggestion I´ll implement whe deploying and cleaning code.